# Is logging requests with id and timestamp the same as tracing?

Tags: logging, architecture, trace, distributed-tracing

I have a server application. I **log** each request when it begins and when it ends (or errors).

Additionally, I create a unique request `id` when they are received and add it to its logs, and also add a `timestamp` for begin and end.

If another child request is created, I do the same, and also include the parent's `id`. I add to the log some useful data like request `method`, `user id`, etc. as it becomes available in each child request.

Is this kind of **logging** exactly the same as **tracing**? In other words, if I'm doing this, there's no need to do tracing, since it's exactly what I'm already doing?

Comment: From my point of view a trace is a chain / sequence of request logs (or spans) [ref](https://www.aspecto.io/blog/jaeger-tracing-the-ultimate-guide/)

Comment: tracing is similar to or a little more than what you are doing. The main idea of tracing is to track the propagation of a request across various components.